# Booth Booking to show what is available in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I currently have a list of vendors who is coming in to rent a booth to display their products in our event. The event rental timeline is some thing like this,

2 weeks rental - 16 Oct to 28 Oct or 30 Oct to 11 Nov

So is there a formula or VBA script, for example vendor A books Booth A from 16 Oct to 28 Oct, and that formula or VBA script can tell me that Booth A is available only on 30 Oct to 11 Nov?

I really need help on this as i have 100 over booths to manage. It's time consuming if i were to scroll through the whole list and check them one by one.

Thanks in advance!

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|           |             |       Zone        | Vendor Type |   1st Half   |            |                 |         |   2nd Half   |             |                 |         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
| Booth No. | terminal id |                   |             | Company Name | Items Sold | Duration        | Remarks | Company Name | Items Sold  | Duration        | Remarks |
| A1        |             | Liang Court Field |             | Aux          | TBC        | 16 Oct - 28 Oct |         | Naeemsouq    | Clothes     | 30 Oct - 11 Nov |         |
| A2        |             | Liang Court Field |             | Craft B      | Burgers    | 16 Oct - 28 Oct |         | Saiko Beer   | Butter Beer | 30 Oct - 11 Nov |         |
| A3        |             | Liang Court Field |             | Alan         | Pho        | 16 Oct - 28 Oct |         |              |             |                 |         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

So if you can see for Booth A3, Alan only took up the first 2 weeks of the rental. And the 2nd half is empty, meaning its available for booking. I have alot of this in my excel. So it's very time consuming to run through the whole 150 booths to check which booth is available on the first or 2nd half of the event for booking.

Comment: There probably is, but I don't understand how your worksheet is set up, where these dates reside, how they relate to the booth in that worksheet, or any other details, so it's impossible to say what the solution might be. Please share some details about how your worksheet is set up. You can use a tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ (Header Location: Spreadsheet) to paste spreadsheet data here in a way that we can use it (That isn't a screenshot). Just highlight what you paste and hit the `{}` in the editor here to format it.

Comment: How do i copy the ASCII table and paste it here? Sorry, its my first time using that website

Comment: it still turns out like garbage :\

Comment: You just missed that last step. After pasting, highlight everything you pasted and click that `{}` button. You can also manually add four spaces before each line or (after highlighting) press `ctrl+k`

Comment: That really helps. Thanks. Where in this data is the 'Booth A' noted? It looks like `Aux` gets a booth from the 16th to 28th of October, but which booth?

Comment: please see the updated data with booths name

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Excel's filter. You can highlight all your data, then select `Home>Editing>Sort & Filter>Filter`. 
[image]

You can then select the column headers, and deselect all non-blank options. 
[image]

This will filter out all rows where the booth is filled. If you want a filtered list where the openings of the first and second half are available, you could create a new column with an if statement that tests whether one or the other is blank. something like `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(J5),ISBLANK(G5)),1,0)` would do the trick (assuming your duration data were in columns J and G). You could then filter based on the new helper column.

If you are looking for a formula option, the following formula will produce a list of unoccupied booths. This formula assumes your booth numbers are in `Column A`, and your Duration is in `Column G`. Adapt the formula as necessary to fit your data. This is a array formula, so you would need to copy and paste it into a cell, then hit `ctrl+shift+enter`

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,(IF(ISBLANK(G3:G5),A3:A5,"")))}
```

Alternatively, if you don't have the latest version of office that has the `TEXTJOIN` formuala, you can do something similar with `CONCAT`, although it will take a little extra work to format it well.  This is also an array formula, so you would need to copy and paste it into a cell, then hit `ctrl+shift+enter`

```
{=CONCAT(IF(ISBLANK(G3:G5),A3:A5,""))}
```

To make it better formatted, you could either put a space after each entry in column A, or alternatively, you can create another column with each element in the column ", " (a coma and a space). If this column were in `Column H` the following formula would produce a formated list of open spaces (again an array formula).

```
{=CONCAT(IF(ISBLANK(G3:G5),A3:A5&H3:H5,""))}
```